# How to define optional data inside TypeScript interface object?

Tags: typescript, interface, option-type

How to define a TypeScript interface that has optional data inside an Object?
What I mean by that:

```
export interface IMyInterface 
{
  name: string;
  data: 
  {
    size: number;
    color?: string;
    [any: string]?: any; // Error on this line!!!
  };
};
```

I know that you can define an optional data using the '?' sign like this:

```
color?: string;
```

but how to define additional-optional-data inside a Object

```
let myObj: IMyInterface = 
{
   name: "theName",
   data:
   {
      size: 10,
      color: "red",
      moreOptionalData: { x: 'y' } // This line will throw an error (incampatable interface)
   }   
};
```

Comment: There's no point to making an index signature optional, since by definition an index signature means that those keys may or may not be there anyway. So it's already kind of optional to begin with. If you just remove the `?` from that index (Eg: `[any: string]: any`), is there a reason it won't satisfy your use case?

Comment: `[any: string]` is telling your data object to be act as an associative array, which is not definable as an optional parameter.  like `data['item_1'] = "item"` and so on. If you've meant for the `any` to be an object array then you can set it up as `any?: any[]`

Comment: @CRice thank you. `[any:string]: any` works!!! Could you please rewrite your "Comment" as an "Answer"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to CRice's comment and OJ-Kwon's insight, the solution was pritty simmple, I just had to drop the '?' sign.

```
export interface IMyInterface 
{
  name: string;
  data: 
  {
    size: number;
    color?: string;
    [any: string]: any; // optional additional data (no need for '?')
  };
};

let myObj: IMyInterface = 
{
   name: "theName",
   data:
   {
      size: 10,
      color: "red",
      moreOptionalData: { x: 'y' } // Now it's OK
   }   
};
```

Comment: This solution works pretty well, but I have a question derived from it. `[any: string]: any;` clashes against `size: number;` if I wanted to replace the `any` with `string` (imagine I wanted the optional additional data to be only strings). How would you fix this? The error I receive is `Property 'size' of type 'number' is not assignable to string index type 'string'.ts(2411)`

Comment: @danivicario - the part inside the square parenthesis must by of type string because object keys are always strings, but the part outside the square parenthesis can be typed. Interface example:  `interface iDemo { [theName: string]: number; }`, use example `let myObj: iDemo = { age: 10, value: 20 }`

Comment: thanks a lot Gil! taking  your answer, this is the problem I have: given `interface iDemo { propertyThatMustBeString: string; [theName: string]: number; }` this fails for me `let myObj: iDemo = { propertyThatMustBeString: "Epshtain", age: 10, value: 20 };` . I want that all the properties that can be created from `[theName: string]: number;` are numbers but I want to be sure that `propertyThatMustBeString` is a `string` and that's what I don't know how to accomplish. Is there any way to say "all the fields that are indexed will be numbers but one field, that will be from another type"?

Comment: @danivicario - Now I see your problem. The TS compiler doesn't know what type `propertyThatMustBeString` is. Because it's matching both types string (from definition) and number (from the `[theName: string]: number`). I need to make some additional resourch. But you can use this workaround - change your object structure to  `interface iDemo { propertyThatMustBeString: string; optional: { [theName: string]: number; }}`

Comment: thanks a lot Gil for the workaround idea :)

Answer (score 1):

index signature itself indicate object can have certain key-based values and as it works without any value, doesn't have lot mean to specify it as optional - reason TSC doesn't allow to specify it as optional via `?`: https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/7118